# How to pass binary data to Mojolicious Minion?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am using the great tool for long running tasks [Minion](https://mojolicious.io/blog/2018/12/10/minion-stands-alone/) ([docs](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Minion))

For queued task I can provide a path to file.
[image]

This works fine if minions are working on same host machine.

But how to create task and pass binary data, if `minions` are running on different host?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this should be:

- store file into database into special table.
- fetch id of this record
- pass this id as parameter to `Minion` task instead of file path

In the example above it will look like: `--allowed=12345`

Then the task sub can connect to database and fetch content of your file file by provided `id`